# Creating a pointer to a class in a function belonging to a different class

Tags: c++, class, pointers

I'm trying to populate a vector of type pointer to class B, which I'll be using later.
When I try to read the vector's element, the value I'm getting is different from what I've given.
Can someone please help me here, what mistake I'm making and how to correct it?
Thanks

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class B {
    public:
    int b;
    B (int n) {
       b = n;
    }
};

std::vector<B*> v;

class A {
    public:
    int a;
    void func(int n);
};

void A::func(int n) {
    B obj_b(n);
    B* ptr = &obj_b;
    v.push_back(ptr);
}

int main() {
    A obj_a;
    obj_a.a = 5;
    obj_a.func(4);
    std::cout<<obj_a.a<<std::endl;
    for (auto it:v) {
        std::cout<<it->b<<std::endl;
    }
}
```

The output I'm getting is:
5,
32765
Whereas the expected output is:
5,
4

Comment: `obj_b` is destroyed right after `A::func()` returns. After that, `&obj_b` becomes a dangling pointer.

Comment: First of all, unless you use inheritance and polymorphism you almost never needs pointers. Use a vector of `B` *objects* instead. And if you have some (for us) unknown requirement to use pointers, use *smart* pointers like `std::unique_ptr`. And then create the object dynamically using `std::make_unique` or if that's not available plain `new`.

Comment: In this case how to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Comment: You are pointing at a value on the stack that will no longer exist when the vector is read — and then reading random garbage left in memory where that stack frame used to be. Please run it with `valgrind` and fix all errors reported there.

Comment: Drop the pointers. [Here's a start](https://godbolt.org/z/f5Mcv8KxT)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using value instead of pointer, as per the comments above:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class B {
    public:
    int b;
    B (int n) {
       b = n;
    }
};

std::vector<B> v;

class A {
    public:
    int a;
    void func(int n);
};

void A::func(int n) {
    v.emplace_back(n);
}

int main() {
    A obj_a;
    obj_a.a = 5;
    obj_a.func(4);
    std::cout<<obj_a.a<<std::endl;
    for (auto& e:v) {
        std::cout<<e.b<<std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Suggestion: Instead of `v.push_back(B(n));` just do `v.emplace_back(n);`

Comment: @TedLyngmo Agreed, I was writing the  answer on the iPad, and wasn’t immediately sure which version of C++ introduced emplace_back. But since the OP is using auto, it would be a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use heap allocations and take advantage of `std::unique_ptr<T>`. Here is the fix:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>


class B
{
public:
    B ( const int n )
    {
       b = n;
    }

    int b;
};

std::vector< std::unique_ptr<B> > v; // use a vector of B pointers
                                     // ( std::unique_ptr<B> )
class A
{
public:
    void func( const int n );

    int a;
};

void A::func( const int n )
{
    v.push_back( std::make_unique<B>( n ) ); // returns a pointer object of type
}                                            // std::unique_ptr<B>

int main ()
{
    A obj_a;
    obj_a.a = 5;
    obj_a.func( 4 );
    std::cout << obj_a.a << std::endl;

    for ( const auto& ptrB : v )
    {
        std::cout << ptrB->b << std::endl; // use -> operator to have access to
    }                                      // ptrB's members

    return 0;
}
```

Hopefully, this helps.

Comment: Using `new` will work, but it does introduce a different problem - you have to `delete` everything you `new` or else it will be leaked. Prefer to use smart pointers rather than raw pointers, let the standard library handle the memory management for you, eg: `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<B>> v; ... v.push_back(std::make_unique<B>(n));`

Comment: That's why I'm reluctant to use 'new', how can I make use of smart pointers here?

Comment: As suggested by @Remy Lebeau, I updated the answer to use smart pointers.

Comment: Fwiw, I wouldn't re-use the variable `B` in the loop, since that is already a declared type and could confuse the reader. Maybe `pB`.

Comment: The best solution is just to not use pointers at all, as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70062576/65863). But if you must use pointers, prefer smart pointers for ownership, use raw pointers only for views not ownership.

Comment: Thank you kind souls for your time and effort.

Comment: @Shailendra If the answers were helpful to you, then please go ahead and choose your accepted answer.